# A limit related to tetration growth rate

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, special-functions, lambert-w, tetration

Assume $a\in\mathbb R,\,e^{-e}<a<e^{1/e}$ and $n\in\mathbb N$.

Let ${^n a}$ denote [tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration):
$${^0a}=1,\quad{^{(n+1)}a}=a^{\left({^n a}\right)}.\tag1$$
It is [well known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Extension_to_infinite_heights) that under these assumptions, the following limit exists:
$${^\infty a} = \lim_{n\to\infty}{^n a} = \frac{W\!\left(-\ln a\right)}{-\ln a} = e^{-W\left(-\ln a\right)},\tag2$$
where $W(z)$ is the [Lambert $W$-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

It is also known that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{{^\infty a} - {^{(n+1)} a}}{{^\infty a} - {^n a}} = {^\infty a} \cdot \ln a.\tag3$$

How can we prove that the following also holds?

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac 1 {{^\infty a} - {^n a}}-\frac{{^\infty a} - {^{(n+1)} a}}{{^\infty a} \cdot \left({^\infty a} - {^n a}\right)^2 \cdot \ln a}\right)=\frac{\ln a}2\tag4$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following Nemo's idea, set $x=^\infty a-^na$, so that $x\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Then
$$\frac{1}{^\infty a-^na}-\frac{^\infty a-^{(n+1)}a}{^\infty a(^\infty a-^na)^2\ln a}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1-\frac{^{(n+1)}a}{^\infty a}}{(^\infty a-^na)^2\ln a}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1-a^{^na-^\infty a}}{x^2\ln a}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1-a^x}{x^2\ln a}=\frac{a^x-x\ln a-1}{x^2\ln a}.$$

Expanding $a^x$ around $0$ as a power series $1+x\ln a+\frac{1}{2}x^2(\ln a)^2+O(x^3)$ gives that this expression, as $x\rightarrow 0$, is
$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}x^2(\ln a)^2+O(x^3)}{x^2\ln a}=\frac{\ln a}{2}+O(x)\rightarrow\frac{\ln a}{2}.$$